# MySQL LEFT JOIN Request can't find a mistake

Tags: mysql, datetime, left-join

I have a table with items that have a datetime column called add_time

I want to do this:

take 5 elements that was added before element with id 10 for example.

I see only one way to doing this, here it is but mysql return zero rows.

```
SELECT i.* 
FROM  `image` AS  `i` 
LEFT JOIN  `image` AS  `i2` ON i.id = i2.id
WHERE i2.id =1317
AND i.`add_date` < i2.`add_date` 
ORDER BY i.add_date DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 5
```

Comment: If you self-join on the criterion that the `id` columns match, but then filter the results for only those where the `add_date` columns differ, you will obviously end up with no results (assuming that there is a uniqueness constraint on `id`, such as it being your primary key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from image
where date_add < (select date_add from image where id = 10)
order by date_add desc
limit 5
```

Comment: dumb question, right answer:) Thanks, you save my time a lot:)